# BING API, missing directive or an assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, bing-api

I have download the new Bing API C# file and added it to my ASP.NET web site, it works perfectly if uses ASP.NET MVC 2.0 but with simple ASP.NET website it shows an error on this line:

```
var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/"));
```

The error is:

> Error 1
>   The type or namespace name 'Bing' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>   c:\Users\jawad\documents\visual studio 2010\WebSites\BingAPI\Default.aspx.cs

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: _a using directive or an assembly reference_? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Verify you have the correct using statement for the API.

2) Verify the API is referenced properly.

3) Verify that your project and the bing api project (or .dll) both have the same .net version selected.

Comment: i downloaded BingSearchContainer.cs file from Microsoft, and on my code behind file of my webpage i am typing "using    BingSearchContainer;"  but i am receiving error, also i am using same .net version

Comment: I got it fixed :) actually i was missing App_Code folder in my project, when i created it and put the .cs file in it, code work fine. Thanks